# Iterating over rows of a dataframe in pandas and changing values

Tags: python, pandas

My question concerns iterating through the rows of a data frame and on each row setting a field based on information in a different data frame. Sorry if this is an elementary question, but I've been through the forums without success on this.

I have two dataframes called sample and lvlslice. I don't have a name for the index on my sample (seems to have gotten lost in the shuffle of randomly picking out some entries). For each row in sample I'm trying to sum the amount field of lvlslice entries with fbid matching my index, and put the result in my new_col.

I can do this with some horrifically awkward for loops, making lists out of index's, etc etc. This seems like simple data manipulation, my main problem is how do I iterate over the loops of my sample data frame, and then set values based on the content of the row?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm particularly interested in what is the right way to do a manipulation such as this, not just how to get my sums.

```
print(sample)

         purchase   new_col
43022    True       0
3423     True       0
43534    True       0

print(lvlslice)

                             fbid   other_stuff  amount
timestamp               
2014-01-03 00:00:10.328000   3424   stuff        320
2014-01-03 00:00:21.419000   5557   stuff        360
2014-01-03 00:00:22.667000   3424   stuff        7000
...
```

Edit: Thanks for the excellent reply, that's useful above and beyond just the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html) and [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html). See below, I modified some of your data to get matching values in the columns, to show the results better.

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.DataFrame({"purchase": True, "new_col": 0},
                      index=[43022, 3424, 43534])

lvlslice = pd.DataFrame({'fbid': [3424, 43534, 3424], 'other_stuff': 'stuff',
                         'amount': [320, 360, 7000]})

df = pd.merge(lvlslice, sample, left_on='fbid', right_index=True)

print df.groupby('fbid')['amount'].sum()
```

This prints:

```
fbid
3424     7320
43534     360
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post so if the code comes out formatted weird, sorry!

I think this is exactly what you asked for, but it is gross and expensive.  For common things like this there is almost always an elegant way to do it already built into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.DataFrame({"purchase": True, "new_col": 0},index=[43022, 3424, 43534])
lvlslice = pd.DataFrame({'fbid': [3424, 43534, 3424], 'other_stuff': 'stuff','amount': [320, 360, 7000]})
sample['total'] = 0

for sampleindex in sample.index:
    for lvlsliceindex in lvlslice.index:
    amount = lvlslice.ix[lvlsliceindex]['amount']
    if sampleindex == lvlslice.ix[lvlsliceindex]['fbid']:
        sample.loc[sampleindex,'total'] += amount

print sample['total']
```

Output:

```
43022       0
3424     7320
43534     360
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

But don't do that, use bananafish's code.

Instead of:

```
print df.groupby('fbid')['amount'].sum()
```

you could get the same result from:

```
df.groupby('fbid').agg('sum')['amount']
```

And if you want to keep rows from sample that have zero for a total around you could do the merge like this:

```
df = pd.merge(lvlslice, sample, left_on='fbid', right_index=True,how='outer').fillna(0)
```